# Importing SVG images to Blender

Tags: import

[image]I'm having trouble with imported images in Blender, they don't respond the same way as the native images on Blender do. I save .svg files with Illustrator and it is vector art. I'm just trying to get an embossed look on these images.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23170/why-cant-i-import-a-svg-file-from-adobe-illustrator

Comment: can you post the image file you are having issues with?

Comment: maybe this tutorial will help? http://www.cgmasters.net/free-tutorials/other/importing-vector-graphics-to-blender/

Comment: What is it about them that isn't working as expected?

Comment: I tried importing the .jpg files as Planes and all I see is a square, the image I want is nowhere to be seen. I was wondering if there is any way that I could convert the curves in the SVG files to meshes that I could extrude? That's the problem I'm having with the SVG files.

Comment: to convert a currve to mesh use Alt+C http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2917/how-can-curves-be-converted-to-meshes

Comment: Try this tutorial, I found it helpful for my needs. [Inkscape to Blender](https://studiogreenleaf.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/inkscape-to-blender/)

Answer (score 7):

I think you will run into problems with such complex paths/curves. Extrude might work but I think beveling wont work well.

For an embossed look I would use the image as a bump map/texture/heigh map:

Add a plane in blender, UV-unwrap it and add your image as a bump map. You should unsharpen your image for a smooth beveling effect.

[image: play with the strenght and distance values in the bump node]

You could even mix differently smoothed images together for a more distinct look.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Blender imports svg files as curve objects. If you're trying to use the art from Illustrator as an image texture, you should export it from Illustrator in a raster format (PNG, JPG, etc).

Comment: I thought Blender didn't import raster images, I'll try it. Thanks.